# Manage ASP.NET session timeout for a single key

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'd like to manage the timemout of a key in a different manner with respect to other keys.

Is it possible?

I mean, let's consider two session keys: "`User`" and "`RedirectUrl`". I'd like to keep my "`User`" session object for 1 hour and my "`RedirectUrl`" session object for 1 minute.

How may I cope with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just wrapping the Session values that you want to expire in another object:

```
[Serializable]
public class SessionUser
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SessionRedirectUrl
{
    public Uri RedirectUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

If there was a mechanism for expiring each session value you would need logic to check the expiry date anyway.

However, as Icarus states, the functionality you are describing might be a cache instead of a session concern.

Comment: Yes, I need not to hit session performance. I think I'll add my own logic after retrieving the wrapped object, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no way, out of the box, to use the Session class in the manner you want. You'd have to use your own solution for this.

`Cache` does have a mechanism to allow you to expire a specific object after certain amount of time but it may not be appropriate for your scenario since `Cache` is shared across all sessions.

You could still use Cache to do this if you prepend some sort of unique identifier to the keys in a way that you can still differentiate between users (for example, prepending the userid to every key) but then you still have to think about the scalability of this approach.

Comment: Yes and when only for one minute then maybe that's just trying to preserve some data for the current request? The Request.Items["myKey"] works the same way as session but the keys last only for the duration of the current request. This means we get storage for the duration of the page life cycle only.